# Reactjs - ordering if else and outer block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a react component which has the following functions:

```
alreadyUpvoted() {
    return this.state.upvotes.indexOf(this.props.context.userId) !== -1
}

alreadyDownvoted() {
    return this.state.downvotes.indexOf(this.props.context.userId) !== -1
}

addUpvote() {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        upvotes: prev.upvotes.concat(this.props.context.userId),
        upvoted: true,
        votes: prev.votes + 1,
    }), () => {
        console.log('add upvote', this.state)
    })
}

removeUpvote() {
    var new_upvotes = this.state.upvotes.concat()
    new_upvotes.pop(this.props.context.userId)
    this.setState(prev => ({
        upvotes: new_upvotes,
        upvoted: false,
        votes: prev.votes - 1,
    }), () => {
        console.log('remove upvote', this.state)
    })
}

addDownvote() {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        downvotes: prev.downvotes.concat(this.props.context.userId),
        downvoted: true,
        votes: prev.votes - 1,
    }), () => {
        console.log('add dowvote', this.state)  
    })
}

removeDownvote() {
    var new_downvotes = this.state.downvotes.concat()
    new_downvotes.pop(this.props.context.userId)
    this.setState(prev => ({
        downvotes: new_downvotes,
        downvoted: false,
        votes: prev.votes + 1,
    }), () => {
        console.log('remove downvote', this.state)
    })
}

postVotesData() {
    var json = {
        upvotes: this.state.upvotes,
        downvotes: this.state.downvotes
    }
    json = JSON.stringify(json)
    console.log(json)
    const url = `/api/reddit/r/${this.props.subreddit}/posts/${this.props.postid}/`
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: json
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response status:', response)
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(res => console.log('response data:', res))
}
```

I have created a `toggleUpvote` function which utilizes all the above functions:

```
toggleUpvote() {
    if (this.alreadyDownvoted()) {
        this.removeDownvote()
        this.addUpvote()
    }
    else if (this.alreadyUpvoted()) {
        this.removeUpvote()
    }
    else {
        this.addUpvote()
    }
    this.postVotesData()
}
```

The problem here is the `this.postVotesData()` is getting executed before the **if-else** block finished.

For the current state, the control should go to else block. But, The `console.log` in `this.postVotesData()` got executed before the `console.log` present in `addUpvote`!!

evidence:
[image]

At the current state, `upvotes` array should have one value after executing of **else** and that array should be used in **PUT**. But, empty array is being **PUT** and then value gets added to array.

I also want the functions inside **if** block to be executed in order. How can I solve this?

Comment: *The console.log in this.postVotesData() got executed before the console.log present in any of the other functions* - there are zero console.log calls in the code you've posted. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Since the behaviour is obviously specific to these functions, the question doesn't make sense without their listings.

Comment: Please provide implementation details of the function you are calling here. It will help us to give the exact answer

Comment: Ya I was adding them. Now I have updated the question

Comment: @SreekarMouli See the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how asynchronous javascript works. I believe you are doing an asynchronous operation like a fetch call, or react's setState(). Both of them(and many other things) in js are async. 
To deal with this, you need to use callbacks or promises. When using promises, you can use the async-await syntax to have a clean code.

```
async toggleUpvote() {
    if (this.alreadyDownvoted()) {
        await this.removeDownvote()
        await this.addUpvote()
    }
    else if (this.alreadyUpvoted()) {
        await this.removeUpvote()
    }
    else {
        await this.addUpvote()
    }
    await this.postVotesData()
}
```

To do this, removeUpvote, addUpvote and postVotesData need to return promises.

If you calling the setState in these functions, you need to provide a callback to setState. Or else you can use the functional-setState pattern.

A simple fix to avoid this problem is to return a promise from your functions similar to the following, and use the async-await syntax as suggested above.

```
addUpvote() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        upvotes: prev.upvotes.concat(this.props.context.userId),
        upvoted: true,
        votes: prev.votes + 1,
    }), () => {
        console.log('add upvote', this.state)
        return resolve(); // Signal that the operation has finished
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: There's no evidence that they return promises. The problem is primarily that the question was poorly asked.

Comment: @estus I agree with that

Answer (score 1):

It may appear like that, but it does not get excecuted before the block is done. All these functions are *started* in that exact order (synchrone), depending on which if/else route.

The reason you may think that, is because these functions are probably async, like an AJAX request. Those work with promises and/or on-complete functions. You might want to look up some tutorials about that, as it's to broad to explain in a simple answer here.
Simply put: With a promise you tell javascript to wait for the result before continueing.

edit: I noticed the react tag, you might want to check out [`await`](https://ewanvalentine.io/using-async-await-in-your-react-apps/). It might take a few reads to understand what is going one, but worth the research.

Comment: I have provided details about `console.log` output

Comment: And the console.log is the first line in each funjction? Or last? I can asure you, all these functions are started in the proper order.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: My answer still stand, especially with your added code :)